# Javascript styling before showing the element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have this node of HTML:

```
body
  div.part-1
  div.part-2
```

By default, the two divs have 0 height. If I define the height for each div in CSS, it's like:

```
.part-1
  height: 200px
.part-2
  height: 300px
```

When the divs shows up, they show up with defined CSS heights (200px and 300px) right a way.

But when styling goes to Javascript, I have some kind of problem, here's my JS:

```
p1 = document.getElementsByClassName('part-1');
p2 = document.getElementsByClassName('part-2');

p1.style.height = '200px';
p2.style.height = '300px';
```

My problem is: When the divs shows up, they show up at 0 height first, then boom, the height instantly increase to the defined height in JS (200px and 300px height). They don't show up the JS defined height right a way, but they show up at 0px of height first..

The result I want to achieve is that when I define a style to an HTML Element by Javscript, it only show the 'defined' styles of the element (not the 'undefined' styles).

Is there any way that I can achieve the result? Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe you are setting the properties with js when the document is ready (DOMContentLoaded or $.document(ready)) and therefor the js is waiting for the page to be loaded. Also it depends where your js is loaded, if in the <head> or <body> tag

Comment: Could you share your entire code to better understand...and I think you kept your JS file at the head section, If it is that one move to body tag.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting everything in a iffy, and place your JavaScript before the end of body tag

```js
(function(){
p1 = document.getElementsByClassName('part-1');
p2 = document.getElementsByClassName('part-2');
p1[0].style.height = '200px';
p2[0].style.height = '300px'; 
}())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS height</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="part-1">
   <p>part1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="part-2">
  <p>part2</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object, so you have to select first item to get the element, `querySelector()` would be a better choice.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much bro!

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the element as display:none and then, with javascript, add display:inherit.

Answer (score 0):

use `querySelector` like this.Because `getElementsByClassName` Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.So you have access through `index`.

```
p1 = document.querySelector('.part-1');
p2 = document.querySelector('.part-2');

p1.style.height = '200px';
p2.style.height = '300px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jquery to update the height of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".part-1").css("height","200px");
  $(".part-2").css("height","300px");
});
```

**OR**
 you can try something like this to keep it smooth

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".part-1").animate({height: "200px"});
  $(".part-2").animate({height: "300px"});
});
```